# Confusion while deploying docker-composer image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been working in a sample ruby-on-rails application and deploying docker image in a linux server (ubuntu 14.04).

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.1.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /rails_docker_demo
WORKDIR /rails_docker_demo
ADD Gemfile /rails_docker_demo/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /rails_docker_demo/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /rails_docker_demo

# CMD bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
# EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    image: atulkhanduri/rails_docker_demos
    volumes:
      - .:/rails_docker_demo
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

deploy.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

docker build -t atulkhanduri/rails_docker_demo .
docker push atulkhanduri/rails_docker_demo

ssh username@ip-address << EOF
docker pull atulkhanduri/rails_docker_demo:latest
docker stop web || true
docker rm web || true
docker rmi atulkhanduri/rails_docker_demo:current || true
docker tag atulkhanduri/rails_docker_demo:latest atulkhanduri/rails_docker_demo:current
docker run -d --restart always --name web -p 3000:3000 atulkhanduri/rails_docker_demo:current
EOF
```

Now my problem is that I'm not able to use `docker-compose` commands like `docker-compose up`, to run the application server.

When I uncomment the last two lines from`Dockerfile` i.e,

```
CMD bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0    
EXPOSE 3000
```

then I'm able to run the server on port `3000` but getting error `could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`. (my database.yml has "db" as host.) This is because `postgres` image is not used as I'm not using `docker-compose` file is not.

#### EDIT:

Output of `docker network ls`:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
b466c9f566a4        bridge              bridge              local               
7cce2e53ee5b        host                host                local               
bfa28a6fe173        none                null                local
```

P.S: I've searched a lot in the internet but not yet able to use the `docker-compose` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assumptions

If I am reading what you've done here correctly, my answer assumes the following two things.

1. You are using docker-compose to run the database container.
2. You are using plain docker commands (not docker-compose) to start the application server ("web").

First, I would suggest not doing that, it is a lot simpler to use docker-compose for both. However, I'll answer based on the above, assuming that there is some valid reason you cannot use docker-compose to run the "web" container.

### About container and network names

When you run the docker-compose command to start the db container, among other things, two things happen.

1. The container is given a new name, composed of the directory you run the compose setup from, the static name in compose (`db`), and a number. So let's say you have this all in a directory name `myapp`, you would have a new container named `myapp_db_1`. You can see what it is named using `docker ps`.
2. A network bridge is created if it didn't already exist, named something like `myapp_default` - again, named after the directory that the compose setup is inside of.

### Connecting to the right network

The problem is that your non-compose container is attached to the default network (probably `docker_default`), but your db container is attached to `myapp_default`. The two networks do not know about each other. You need to connect them. It probably makes more sense to tell the web app container to attach to the compose network.

First, get the correct network name. You can see all networks using `docker network ls`. It might look like this:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                       DRIVER              SCOPE
c1f5764a112b        bridge                     bridge              local
175efb89adef        docker_default             bridge              local
5185ff0e1054        myapp_default              bridge              local
```

Once you have the correct name, update your run command to know about the network using the `--network` option.

```
docker run -d --restart always --name web \
    -p 3000:3000 --network myapp_default \
    atulkhanduri/rails_docker_demo:current
```

Once it is attached to the proper network, the name "db" should resolve correctly.

If you used docker-compose to start both of them, this would not be necessary (this is one of the things docker-compose just takes care of for you silently).

### Getting this to run on your server

In the comments, you mention that you are having some issues with compose on the server. Specifically you said:

> Do I need to copy my complete project on the server? Can't I run the application from docker image only? Actually, I've copied `docker-compose` in server and it throws errors for `Gemfile`, then I copied `Gemfile`, then it says it should be a rails app. So I guess I need to copy my complete folder in server. Can you please confirm?

Let's look at some parts of your Dockerfile. I'll add some comments inline.

```
## Make a new directory, and then make it the current directory
RUN mkdir /rails_docker_demo
WORKDIR /rails_docker_demo

## Copy Gemfile and Gemfile.lock into this directory from outside
ADD Gemfile /rails_docker_demo/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /rails_docker_demo/Gemfile.lock

## Run the bundle installer, which will install to this directory
RUN bundle install

## Finally, copy everything from the outside local dir to here
ADD . /rails_docker_demo
```

So, clearly, `/rails_docker_demo` is your application directory within the container. You've installed a bunch of stuff here, and this will become a part of your image. When you push your image to the registry, then pull it down on the server (as you do in the deploy script), this will all come with it.

Now let's look at (some of) docker-compose.yml.

```yaml
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - .:/rails_docker_demo
```

Here you have defined a volume mount, mounting the current directory (wherever docker-compose.yml lives) as `/rails_docker_demo`. When you do that, whatever happens to exist on the server is now available in `/rails_docker_demo`, but this mount undoes all the work from Dockerfile that I just mentioned above. Instead of having the resources you installed when you built the image, you have only whatever is on the server in the `.` directory. The mount is on top of the image's existing `/rails_docker_demo` directory, hiding its contents and replacing them with whatever is on the server at the moment.

Unless there is a reason you put this mount here, you probably just need to remove that volume mount from docker-compose.yml. You will still need docker-compose.yml on the server, but you should not need the rest of it (aside from the image, of course).

This mount you have done is a useful thing - for development purposes. It would let you use the container to run the application and quickly have code changes show up (without rebuilding the image). But in the case of your deployment, it is just causing trouble.

Comment: I've tried using the `docker-compose` (`docker-compose up`) command in `deploy.sh`, replacing `docker run` command. But it throws an error `Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent.` It would be helpful if you provide me the command to run web app using `docker-compose`.

Comment: Also my `docker network ls` shows
`NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
b466c9f566a4        bridge              bridge              local               
7cce2e53ee5b        host                host                local               
bfa28a6fe173        none                null                local`

I've updated this in question.

Comment: @AtulKhanduri Are you copying docker-compose.yml to the server? I see where you are building the image, pushing to the registry. I see that you ssh to the server, pull the image, and start it up, but if docker-compose.yml is not available on the server side, then docker-compose won't have it available. Which is what your error suggests: ("Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent.")

Comment: Do I need to copy my complete project on the server? Can't I run the application from docker image only? Actually, I've copied `docker-compose` in server and it throws errors for `Gemfile`, then I copied `Gemfile`, then it says it should be a rails app. So I guess I need to copy my complete folder in server. Can you please confirm?

Comment: @AtulKhanduri This is probably due to your volume mount. I've edited my answer to add a section about that problem.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. Now I've removed the `volumes` section from docker-compose and created a build, push to the DockerHub and pull the image into the server. Also, I have copied `docker-compose.yml` on the server. But when I'm running `docker-compose up` then it searches for Dockerfile, which isn't available and when I copied the Dockerfile in the server, then a "missing Gemfile error" occurs. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AtulKhanduri It is probably looking for a Dockerfile because you specified `build`. You don't need the build dir specified in your deployed docker-compose.yml, try removing that line. You also don't need `command` if you built it into the image already using `CMD`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dan. Now the application server is up and running and I'm able to run the server with docker-compose. Actually, there was also a problem from my end. In `Dockerfile`, I've selected working directory in root (`WORKDIR rails_docker_demo`) and I added the code in home (`ADD . ~/rails_docker_demo`). Server is running fine even if I specify `build` in docker-compose.

Comment: +1 and accepted the answer, Thanks. One more thing, I want to ask: what should I specify in the `docker-compose` so that code from docker container will be copied to the local machine? I've tried to specify `volumes`, but obviously, it saves the code inside docker instance.

Comment: @AtulKhanduri The only way you can really do that is to set up some kind of sync/copy mechanism like rsync or ssh/scp, and copy the files from the container to the external host. I'm not sure why you need to do that, though? The application is wrapped up in the container already. If you need the code on the remote host, you can always put it there using some other mechanism, like a git repository.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I was just wondering that if docker has some feature like this.

Comment: Dan, can you please help me to [this docker question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41395427/2945616)

Answer (score -1):

Try moving the `EXPOSE` above `CMD`, .e.g.

```
FROM ruby:2.1.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /rails_docker_demo
WORKDIR /rails_docker_demo
ADD Gemfile /rails_docker_demo/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /rails_docker_demo/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /rails_docker_demo

EXPOSE 3000
CMD bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it'll work, as I'm able to run the app server using `docker` but not `docker-compose`, and thus `db` container is in different network than the app server, as suggested by Dan Lowe's answer. Although, I'll try your solution.