# Communication between two Docker containers on macOS 10.12

Tags: macos, docker, redis

I'm working with Docker 1.12.5 on macOS 10.12, and am setting up a development environment with with I have an **application** image, and a shared **redis** image which has some pre-populated configuration variables.

Even after following a few tutorials (and reading about how `docker0` isn't available on Mac) I'm struggling to connect the two containers.

I start my `redis` image using:

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 (IMAGE ID)
```

In my `redis` image, I have:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
dffb89854618        d59                 "docker-entrypoint.sh"   20 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds       0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   drunk_williams
```

And **from my Mac** I can successfully connect via the `redis-cli` command without issue.

However when I start a simple `ubuntu` image, I can't seem to connect to this separate `redis` image:

```
root@2d4eda315f4f:/# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:03
          inet addr:172.17.0.3  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20707 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:28252929 (28.2 MB)  TX bytes:635848 (635.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:680 (680.0 B)  TX bytes:680 (680.0 B)
root@2d4eda315f4f:/# telnet localhost 6379
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@2d4eda315f4f:/# telnet 172.17.0.3 6379
Trying 172.17.0.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Is this a result of not having the `docker0` interface available in the host? Is there some straightforward workaround for allowing these containers to communicate (when being run on the same host) in a development environment?

**Update:** Attempting to use named containers, I still can't connect.

```
docker run -d --name redis_server redis
```

Results in:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
5d05820aa985        redis               "docker-entrypoint.sh"   43 hours ago        Up 1 seconds        6379/tcp                 redis_server
```

But then if I start a new Ubuntu container:

```
root@e92b47419bc4:/# redis-cli -h redis_server
Could not connect to Redis at redis_server:6379: Name or service not known
```

I'm not sure how to find/connect to the first `redis_server` container.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Each container has its own localhost

Each service runs in its own container. From the perspective of the Ubuntu container, redis is not listening on localhost.

### Use Docker networks

To get your containers to communicate, they should be on the same Docker network. This consists of three steps:

1. Create a Docker network
2. Give your containers names
3. Attach your containers to the network you created

With this done, the containers can talk to each other using their names as if they were hostnames.

There's more than one way to skin this cat... I will look at two in this answer, but there are probably a few other ways to do it that I am not familiar with (like using Kubernetes or Swarm, for instance).

### Doing it by hand

You can create a network for this application using `docker network` commands.

```
# Show the current list of networks
docker network ls

# Create a network for your app
docker network create my_redis_app
```

When you run the redis container, make sure it has a name, and is on this network. You can expose the ports externally (to macOS) if you want to (using `-p`), but that is not necessary just for other containers to talk to redis.

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name redis_server --network my_redis_app <IMAGE ID>
```

Now run your Ubuntu container. You can name it as well if you like, but I won't bother in this example because this one isn't running any services.

```
docker run -it --network my_redis_app ubuntu bash
```

Now from inside the Ubuntu container, you should be able to reach redis using the name `redis_server`, as if it were a DNS name.

### Doing it using Compose

I tend to build setups like this using Compose, because it's easier to write it into a YAML file (IMO). Here's an example of the above, re-written in docker-compose.yml form:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: <IMAGE ID>
    networks:
      - my_redis_app
    ports: 6379:6379
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    networks:
      - my_redis_app
networks:
  my_redis_app:
    driver: bridge
```

With this in place, you can run `docker-compose up -d redis` and have your redis service online using a specific Docker network. Compose will create the network for you, if it doesn't already exist.

It makes less sense to run the Ubuntu container that way... it is interactive, of course. But I assume once you have redis going, you will add some kind of application container, and perhaps a web proxy like nginx... just put the others under `services` as well, and you can manage them all together.

Since `ubuntu` is interactive, you can run it interactively:

```
# without -d, container is run interactively
docker-compose run ubuntu bash
```

And now in Ubuntu, you should be able to connect to redis using its name, which in this example is simply `redis`.

Comment: Is this the case on Mac as well? I attempted the above, to no avail. (See update to question.)

Comment: @CraigOtis Yes, it is. See  my updated answer, I forgot to mention you should use `--link` also. I tend to use docker-compose for this stuff, where you write this all into a YAML file instead of fiddling with the commandline flags... forgot about it before.

Comment: Right, I've been avoiding `--link` since it has been deprecated: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/ Seeing as this config is for a new project, I'd like to avoid starting it with deprecated tooling. :-)

Comment: @CraigOtis Thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't noticed that `--link` had been deprecated. I rewrote the answer to use user-defined networks instead. I also included an example using docker-compose, since I believe it's usually easier to deal with.

Comment: Phew. The custom network route _did_ work! However without the custom network, if they're using the default `bridge` network, they don't - so it seems important to get them off the default? Even though `docker network inspect bridge` shows both containers, they cannot communicate with each other.

Comment: @CraigOtis It is odd that the `default` network did not work (if they were both on it). I would expect that should have worked... I don't have a great explanation for it.

Comment: Excellent and simple answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Is there any reason this shouldn't work for a third container? I was able to get two to communicate (a host & proxy kind of situation) but I wasn't able to curl the "proxy" from a third machine.

Comment: @Russell You should post a question, not ask in comments. People don't read comments on old questions - but they do read new questions and answer them. There's no reason you can't use a docker network with 3 or more containers, but your use of the word "proxy" makes me think you should post a question with your specific details for someone to answer. It is probably not the same situation as this question.